# modify swift snake and ladder game for more than one player

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to modify my code that I managed to create for a simple game of snake and ladder in Swift for one player. below here is a successfully working code for that:

```
let finalSquare = 25
var playersLocation: Int = 0

var won = false

var board = [Int](count: finalSquare + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
board[03] = +08; board[06] = +11; board[09] = +09; board[10] = +02
board[14] = -10; board[19] = -11; board[22] = -02; board[24] = -08

//roll the dice
func rollDice ()->Int {
    let value = Int(arc4random_uniform(6)+1)
    return value
}

while won == false {
//roll the dice
    var advanceplayer = rollDice()
//check the position
    var advance: Int = playersLocation + advanceplayer
//check if it hits the magic number
    if playersLocation < board.count{
        var magicNumber: Int = board[playersLocation]
        advance + magicNumber
    }

    //check if player won
    if playersLocation >= board.count {
        won == true
        print("you won")
        break
    }else{
        playersLocation = playersLocation + advanceplayer
    }
}
```

now with the code working, I want to modify such in a way that I have 3 players(a,b,c) and I want to insert them inside the game.I am pretty much stuck here:

```
let finalSquare = 25
var playersLocation: Int = 0
var players: [String: Int] = ["a": 0, "b": 0, "c":0]

var won = false

var board = [Int](count: finalSquare + 1, repeatedValue: 0)
board[03] = +08; board[06] = +11; board[09] = +09; board[10] = +02
board[14] = -10; board[19] = -11; board[22] = -02; board[24] = -08

board

//roll the dice
func rollDice ()->Int {
    let value = Int(arc4random_uniform(6)+1)
    return value
}

var count: Int = 0

while won == false {
    for player in players.values{


        var advanceplayer = rollDice()
        var advance: Int = player + advanceplayer


        if advance < board.count{
            var magicNumber: Int = board[advance]
            advance + magicNumber
        }

        if advance >= board.count {
            won == true
            print("you won")
            break
        }else{

        advance + advanceplayer

        }
    }
}
```

somehow the player position does not increment, and I have no idea how to keep track of whether a,b, or c won the game. where did it go wrong ?

Comment: You have a debugger. Debug!

Answer (score 0):

When you update each player's position, you aren't reassigning it to that player's slot in the `players` map. That'll be hard to do with your current code because you're iterating over the `players` map's values and ignoring its keys. Instead, enumerate over both keys and values, update each player's position, then stick the new value back in `players`.

Answer (score 0):

You are never storing the player's new position back into the `players` dictionary, so on each iteration of the while-loop, each player's position is being reset to zero.

Also, you are never making use of `magicNumber`; the result of the following expression is never being stored anywhere:

```
advance + magicNumber
```

Perhaps you meant to store the result back into `advance`, like this:

```
advance += magicNumber
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to your problem with multiplayer.

```
let finalSquare = 25
var players: [String: Int] = ["a": 0, "b": 0, "c":0]

var won = false

var board = [Int](repeating: 0, count: finalSquare + 1)
board[03] = +08; board[06] = +11; board[09] = +09; board[10] = +02
board[14] = -10; board[19] = -11; board[22] = -02; board[24] = -08


func rollDice ()->Int {
    let value = Int(arc4random_uniform(6)+1)
    return value
}

whileLoop: while won == false {
    for (player, score) in players {
        var playerScore = score
        //roll the dice
        let diceValue = rollDice()
        //check the position
        playerScore += diceValue
        //check if it hits the magic number
        if playerScore < board.count {
            if board[playerScore] != 0 {
                playerScore += board[playerScore]
            }
        } else {
            won == true
            print("\(player) WON")
            break whileLoop
        }
        players[player] = playerScore
    }
}
```